# cant scroll down and no scroll bar on Ipad only

Tags: css, ipad, scroll

Ive searched for a few hours now on Google, and am coming up with absolutely nothing, for some reason I cant scroll down on my ipad with this site..

http://armoura.hailstorm-technologies.com

Ive tried variations of overflows including `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on body and html but to no avail.

The issue is only with the Ipad, as it loads a mobile site on mobile devices.

Im unsure what code to include as I cant find the source of what might be causing the issue.

It works with 2 fingers at times if that means anything, just wondering is there any js available where I could overwrite whatever is causing this.

Thanks

Comment: I have isolated the issue to the jquery.ui.touch.js file, so Ill need to check is there something in that code causing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a jquery.ui.touch.js file in the site, this was preventing a vertical scroll.